# I do not understand an inequality used to prove that e is bigger/equal to exp(1)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, inequality, exponential-function

I have seen the following inequalies:

$$e \geq 1+1+\sum \limits_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}=s_{n}
\implies e\geq \lim_{n\to\infty}s_{n}=exp(1)$$

Based on this information, how can one explain the implication? Why would $$e\geq \lim_{n\to\infty}s_{n}$$ be true? I only know that $e \geq 1+1+\sum \limits_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}=s_{n}$.

Wouldn't the implication also imply $\sum \limits_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!} = \sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!} = \lim_{n\to\infty}s_{n}$?

Comment: What is your definition of $e$?

Comment: Is the question not answerable with the information that I gave? I am not so advanced in math so I do not know. If I would write down everything that the professor wrote down leading up to what I have written it would take too long, for me and for everyone reading the question.

Comment: probably the definition of $e$ of the OP is $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1{n}\right)^n$. Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1975485/prove-using-an-inequality-that-e-is-irrational

Comment: @Masacroso my question is less how you prove e. My main question is actually formulated in the last sentence, which is a question about the relation between $\sum \limits_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}$ and $\sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you have a convergent sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ and a number $M$ such that $(\forall n\in\Bbb N):x_n\leqslant M$, you also have $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n\leqslant M$. If you apply this to $(s_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ and to the number $e$, you get what you want.

Answer (score 2):

This is a consecuence of the following statement:

Let be $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}, \{y_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ two convergent sequences, such that $x_k\ge y_k,~~~ \forall k\ge N_0, N_0\in\mathbb{N}$. If $x_n\to a$ and $y_n\to b$, then: 
$a\ge b$.

In this case, $x_n$ is a constant sequence with unique value is $e$.